# Plot X-Y graph in Simulink by 2 arrays derived from Matlab workspace

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, simulink

I have 2 uni-dimentional arrays in workspace, one (xarray) is to be used as the x-axis and the other (yarray) as the y-axis.

```
xarray =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

yarray =

   500   200   800     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

What I want to do in Simulink is to read these arrays from the workspace and generate a X-Y graph. I can easily do that from the Matlab command-line `(figure; plot(xarray, yarray))`, however, I want to do it from Simulink.

I've tried to read each array from workspace by using two "for workspace" blocks which I then connected to the corresponding inputs of a 'X-Y graph', however, the error I got was:

> Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of
>   'simulink_model/XY Graph/Mux' is a one dimensional vector with 18
>   elements.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See also the `XY Graph` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simulink can be a bit tricky when using external matrices.

So a couple of things:
1) matrices need to have there array as columns (fortunatly you can do the transpose operation in simulink itself)

2) you need the first column to represt time-entry of the array:
so in your case, for the first input you can use `[xarray; xarray]'`, and the second input, you can use [xarray; yarray]' (provided, of course xarray doesn't change)

3) don't forget to modify the scope preferences to see all the data (default maxes to [-1;1])

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it proved very useful! It's difficult to believe that Simulink is so tricky for such a theoretically simple task.